# Type 'Ref<number>' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, indexing, ref

I want to call `myArray[refVariable]` in Vue. How to fix following error in Vue/Typescript:
`Type 'Ref<number>' cannot be used as an index type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `refVariable`, use `refVariable.value`.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted when you can.

Comment: I can't: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". I'll do later

Comment: Hence the `when you can` part.